# Using the Now() function in CAML Query?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, caml-renderpattern

i am trying to get the 3 most upcoming events from the current date and time (The current data and time refers the time everytime my web part loads. Basically it is not a fixed date and picks up the time everytime my web part is loaded)
Here is my Query. How should I modify it to achieve this?

```
 <Query>
 <Where>
  <And>
     <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2012-03-21T12:18:55Z</Value>
     </Geq>
     <IsNotNull>
        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
     </IsNotNull>
  </And>
 </Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' />
</OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<Today/>` instead of the hardcoded value

```
<Query> 
 <Where> 
  <And> 
     <Geq> 
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' /> 
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value> 
     </Geq> 
     <IsNotNull> 
        <FieldRef Name='Title' /> 
     </IsNotNull> 
  </And> 
 </Where> 
 <OrderBy> 
  <FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' /> 
 </OrderBy> 
</Query>
```

Comment: sorry,Per Jakobsen but its not working for me, n by simply looking at the code ,it's have to work  but unfortunately it's not working for me,it's showing all the events from list.

Comment: i resolved this issue by simple making  IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' to IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by querying for all events greater than now() ordered by date, ascending. Then limit the query to 3 rows and you have all your data!

Let me know if you need help creating the query itself, and please post what you have if you do.

Comment: Hey Zork  I just posted my Query. If you take a look at it, where I have specified now() there is             <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2012-03-21T12:18:55Z</Value> Will this change accordingly during runtime?

Comment: Per posted it before i could do it! his code should work perfectly