# CAML query for current date

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml

I want to get all items from the list, which has a start date from `date.now` or later in time.

This is what I thought would work:

```
var dateNow = Date.now();

 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    "<View>" +
    "<Query>" +
    "<Where>" +
    "<And>" +
    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + txtForNamn.value +</Value></Eq>" +
    "<Geq><FieldRef Name='vpux'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dateNow + "</Value></Geq>" +
    "</And>" +
    "</Where>" +
    "</Query>" +
    "</View>");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace

```
<Geq>
   <FieldRef Name='vpux'/>
   <Value Type='Text'>" + dateNow + "</Value>
</Geq>
```

with

```
<Geq>
    <FieldRef Name='vpux'/>
    <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Now /></Value>
</Geq>
```

You can use `<Today />` as well. `IncludeTimeValue` is, obviously, for including time in the query.

Comment: how does it look like when using "<today />"? I don't think I want to include time. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Using "Today", without including time, would look like: <Geq><FieldRef Name='vpux'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Geq>

Comment: now it says "Error. Cannot complete this action.", I get the same when I'm trying to get from an earlier date :/

Comment: Try setting the IncludeTimeValue to 'TRUE'. Read the following resource as well: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32187/using-the-now-function-in-caml-query

Comment: Should there not be and ending `</Value>` tag above?

Comment: Thanks! Missed that one. The query with "Today" should look like this:  <Geq><FieldRef Name='vpux'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Geq>